# How to write a field as Firestore type reference

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

One of the given types of Firestore is the reference type. I'm able to write it and access it on the console provided by Google. But I'm not sure how to write a field as reference using my Go API.

I tried to write it as a string following the format thinking it would bind to the correct type as long as it followed the format specified. But I was wrong.

I didn't find this in the docs or maybe I just didn't understand it. Anyway, here what I've tried to so far:

```
ref, _, err := client.Collection(collection).Add(context.Background(), map[string]interface{}{
    "my_field": "/users/stYbm0Jkl3ngeWj3fxUL4KZuu44Oae2"
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On all client platforms, you write a reference type by providing a Reference object as the field value, not a string.  For go, this looks like it should be a [DocumentRef](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentRef) type object created with the [Doc](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#Client.Doc) method.  The SDK will convert that into the appropriate field type.

When you read the document back again, the field should also appear as a DocumentRef type object on the client.